# postfix : list of all email addresses accepted

Tags: email, postfix

I would like to know if there is a way, internal to postfix or external (script or other) allowing to know the complete list of all the valid email addresses accepted for reception of mail by a postfix server for its administrator?

Otherwise, apart from manually collecting all these addresses and registering them in the secondary MX (in relay_recipient_maps), how do you do it?

Thanks

Comment: you almost certainly **do not need** a secondary MX, having one is **almost always** a mistake.   See [MX Backup service](https://serverfault.com/questions/47312/mx-backup-service/47325#47325)

Comment: @cas
I am in the FWI so in a hurricane area often prone to long power cuts, so having an MX backup elsewhere in the world is a necessity for me.
I have one, which works well. The only thing is that I wanted to automate the filling of relay_recipient_maps in case I forget to update it when changing the main server.

Comment: I have no idea what FWI is (*Fossilized Walrus Ivory* is the most interesting definition I found) but I get what a hurricane is, ditto for long power cuts.  OK, that's possible a reason to need a secondary MX.

Comment: FWI = French West Indies ;)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_West_Indies

Answer (score 2):

Short version: there is no deterministic solution

The default configuration of Postifx is to allowed delivery to local users - but postfix does not define what "local users" are. After any address re-writing on incoming emails, it calls getent() or similar to find the uid. This relies on the name service to search the supported user databases - that could be the local users in /etc/passwd, in a NIS database, LDAP or other name service.

There's also a getent command which, without modifiers, will return a list of all the local users it can find, however not all the naemservice backends are enumerable.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but then what simple method would automate the filling of relay_recipient_maps of the MX backup? There wouldn't be an application that would be able to locally test everything that is possible to deduce an exhaustive list?

Comment: no, there is no "simple method".   You need to 1. make a list of all sources of user account data. 2. figure out how to extract that data from that source (`getent passwd` is a good start, probably do most of the job if nsswitch.conf is configured properly).  3. copy the usernames to the remote server, and generate the `relay_recipients` map from it. 4. don't forget  your `alias_database` / `alias_maps` or `virtual_alias_*` if you use them.   5. anything else listed in `local_recipient_maps` (default: `local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps`) that isn't already covered.

Comment: The point is that there is no existing tool that magically does it all.  It's a custom job, you'll need to do it yourself to cater for how your mail server is set up.

Comment: I thank you. I know all that, it's what I already do in a more or less complete way, and it is inevitably subject to error or forgetfulness, which is why I was wondering if there were not tools for that. Disappointed to learn that no, but I will continue to do without.

Comment: that's what scripts are for: figure out the manual procedure, write a script to automate it.  update the script when something changes (e.g. if you configure postfix to use mysql or something for aliases or virtual aliases or whatever).  Automation is good for eliminating forgetfulness and human error.   That's what I meant by "it's a custom job".

Comment: You are right. I need to find some time to devote to it.

Comment: Since most of the job will be extracting text or other data from various sources and transforming it into another form (the relay_recipients map), **learn some `perl`** - there is no better tool for doing that kind of job.  The language is designed for it and there are countless library modules for easily working with data from all kinds of sources - sql databases, ldap, berkeley db files, csv, json, xml, and pretty much anything else you might need to work with.

Comment: It's also useful to learn `make`, at least enough to write basic rules. It's a great tool for defining dependency relationships between files, so you can write rules that say, e.g. `/etc/aliases.db` depends on /etc/aliases *and* that you build the former from the latter by running `newaliases`.  so to rebuild aliases.db when /etc/aliases changes you just run `make`.   I configure my postfix (e.g. to generate anti-spam rules from multiple source files) with various scripts I've written tied together with a Makefile so I don't have to remember to run a dozen scripts, I just run `make`.

Comment: it only re-generates map files etc when their source files have changed, and reloads or restarts postfix as needed, depending on what changed (some changes, like master.cf, require a restart of postfix, most only require a reload).